# Rails / activerecords - group by and order by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to perform `:group` and `:order` on my module, since Mysql does group by before order by you get mixed results and not what you expected.

the SQL solution for that would be:

```
SELECT * FROM 

(
select * from `my_table` order by timestamp desc
) as my_table_tmp

group by catid

order by nid desc
```

how can I write that in ruby using activerecord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use the Arel methods directly:

```
MyTable.from("(SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as my_table").group(:catid).order("nid DESC")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
query = <<-sql_statement

  SELECT * FROM 

  (
  select * from `my_table` order by timestamp desc
  ) as my_table_tmp

  group by catid

  order by nid desc

sql_statement

result = MyTable.connection.execute(query)
```

You can also use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)`.

To traverse through the records returned use `result.each`.

Example (from the mysql2 gem [repo](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2)):

```
results.each do |row|
  # conveniently, row is a hash
  # the keys are the fields, as you'd expect
  # the values are pre-built ruby primitives mapped from their corresponding field types in MySQL
  # Here's an otter: http://farm1.static.flickr.com/130/398077070_b8795d0ef3_b.jpg
end
```